# SQLite DLL fails to load from WPF app

Tags: c#, sqlite, dll, reference

I've done some research on this problem and have seen a handful of possible solutions, but nothing that has worked for me.

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite.dll' or one of its
>   dependencies. The specified module could not be found.

I have a WPF application that uses SQLite. On my development machine (Windows 7, 64-bit, Visual Studio 2010), everything works just fine. Over in the QA department, everything works fine. But on the build machine (Windows Server 2008, 64-bit) and over in customer service (32-bit), it gives the error.

My .sln consists of 3 projects - two .exe and one lib (used by both .exe projects and containing the SQLite logic). All 3 have 2 configurations, Debug and Release, and each version compiles to x86. The SQLite dll is in the execution directory.

I have 3 System.Data.SQLite entries in my GAC, which has been verified as why I'm having success on my computer but not certain others, not that I know why it wouldn't be using the dlls found in the executing directory. All GAC entries are version 1.0.66.0, have the same public key token, and are associated with MSIL, x86, and AMD64, respectively. Removing the files from the GAC allowed me to reproduce the error until I changed the project references to "copy local," at which time it again worked on my computer (and still not on the others).

Not sure how smart this was, but I decided to attempt a dynamic load of the dll (while still using references in my projects), checking whether I was running in a 32-bit or 64-bit environment, and using Assembly.LoadFrom to load the SQLite dll for the correct bits. That code executes successfully and goes for the 32-bit version on my 64-bit machine, which I assume is because of the x86 compile platform. Regardless, it hasn't changed the error I see on the other machines.

Suggestions as to how to resolve this issue?

**edited: reflect results after removing references from the GAC**

Comment: Have you tried using something like [DependencyWalker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to figure what's missing?

Comment: yeah dependency walker and fusion viewer would be good to debug this.

Comment: I have used Dependency Walker occasionally, but not enough to say I'm comfortable with my skills there. I load up my .exe (and after that, the dll that does most of the work with SQLite - with same results) in Dependency Walker, and the only thing that shows up under it is MSCOREE.DLL. Surely I'm misunderstanding what I should be seeing here, but shouldn't I be seeing the .dlls that my file depends on? I can't even compile without a reference to the SQLite dll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem in the past. I build to versions: one referencing System.Data.SQLite x32 and the other x64.

Comment: I'm hoping it doesn't come to that... but I'm not seeing any good alternatives at the moment.

Comment: OK, I am conceding and this is where I am at -- the dual build. I haven't actually done a dual build like this before. I mistakenly thought it would be easy :) Anyway, if I build as 64-bit, I need to add the 64-bit SQLite reference, and it exists nicely with the 32-bit, just with a different name. Successful execution of the code aside (because that doesn't seem to work), when I shift to 32-bit, I get all sorts of errors saying that SQLiteConnection exists in both references (duh). I don't need to have 2 .csproj files, do I?

Comment: For the record, I was creative with build events in order to get the correct version of the SQLite dll to the correct location.

Comment: Yes, 2 projects each one referencing one version of SQLite dll. Don't forget to set the target platform too!